# Mongodb crashes when the same collection in accessed by two different python script using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nohup

I have two python scripts, **currentdataupload.py** and **productioncount.py** on my Ubuntu server. **currentdataupload.py** uploads dummy current data and **productioncount.py** accesses that data to do some calculations. The code runs perfectly in other scenarios without disrupting the MongoDB, but when I run both of these codes simultaneously using **nohup** after a few seconds it exits the mongoDB service and is no longer able to upload or retrieve data. I would like to know if I am doing the entire process the right way or I am messing up somewhere big time.

## Error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python_codes/currentdataupload.py", line 38, in <module>
    result = posts.insert_one(post_data)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 630, in insert_one
    bypass_doc_val=bypass_document_validation),
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 535, in _insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, bypass_doc_val)
 File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 516, in _insert_one
    check_keys=check_keys)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 244, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 372, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise error
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 239, in command
    read_concern)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 96, in command
    response = receive_message(sock, 1, request_id)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 123, in receive_message
    header = _receive_data_on_socket(sock, 16)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 161, in _receive_data_on_socket
   raise AutoReconnect("connection closed")
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: connection closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 543, in connect
    sock = _configured_socket(self.address, self.opts)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 452, in _configured_socket
    sock = _create_connection(address, options)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 436, in _create_connection
    raise err
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 429, in _create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python_codes/productioncount.py", line 267, in <module>
    result = col2.find_one({"date": date, "machine": machine})
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1014, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1090, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1012, in _refresh
    self.__read_concern))
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 850, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 844, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 855, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 99, in send_message_with_response
    with self.get_socket(all_credentials, exhaust) as sock_info:
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 163, in get_socket
    with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 582, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket_no_auth()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 628, in _get_socket_no_auth
    sock_info = self._check(sock_info)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 682, in _check
    return self.connect()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 555, in connect
    _raise_connection_failure(self.address, error)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 65, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise AutoReconnect(msg)
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: what is the error log indects? you could view that in /var/log/mongodb.log or something checking if the file handler number has reached the limits, it's very easy for Python users to open too many connections to the DB and case the DB to refuse service and you should paste the scripts for us to diagnose the problem, at least the part of how you connecting the  DB

Comment: @armnotstrong there you go, I updated it with the error log.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's should be a connection pool problem, what does the log in `/var/log/mongodb.log` say? should be quite obvious in that log

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB shouldn't crash. Please file a bug report, including the Python script you run and a complete MongoDB logfile, at jira.mongodb.org.